# Invalidoperationexpression was unhandled - OleDbCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update a database but keep getting the error in the title. Any ideas here is all the relevant code:

```
IDValue = Login.lb.Text
lblIDRunner.Text = IDValue

dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
dbSource = "Data Source = H:\Computer Project\bin\Debug\projectdatabase.accdb"

RunnerConnection.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

RunnerConnection.Open()

sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblDetails Where RunnerID = @RunnerID"
daRunnerDetails = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, RunnerConnection)
daRunnerDetails.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RunnerID", lblIDRunner.Text)
daRunnerDetails.Fill(dsRunnerDetails, "Details")
RunnerConnection.Close()
Dim cbRunners As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daRunnerDetails)


dsRunnerDetails.Tables("Details").Rows(0).Item(1) = txtUserFirstname.Text
dsRunnerDetails.Tables("Details").Rows(0).Item(2) = txtuserlastname.Text
dsRunnerDetails.Tables("Details").Rows(0).Item(3) = txtUserDOB.Text
dsRunnerDetails.Tables("Details").Rows(0).Item(4) = txtUserEmail.Text
dsRunnerDetails.Tables("Details").Rows(0).Item(5) = txtUserNumber.Text
dsRunnerDetails.Tables("Details").Rows(0).Item(6) = txtUserGender.Text
dsRunnerDetails.Tables("Details").Rows(0).Item(7) = txtUserWeight.Text
daRunnerDetails.Update(dsRunnerDetails, "Details")
MsgBox("Data updated")
RunnerConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Try `daRunnerDetails.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@RunnerID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(lblIDRunner.Text)` to specify the type of the query parameter, as the error implies is required.  I am guessing that the ID is an integer, so you may need to adjust as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark, what do i need to declare oledbtype as?

Comment: `OleDbType` is an enumeration in `System.Data.OleDb` - [here are the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) showing the valid types.